# Directory entry | Error when using Encryption or SSL

Tags: c#, ssl, active-directory, directoryentry

I'm trying to encrypt my Active Directory access with the following code:

```
// Already tried different paths (LDAP://domain.com, LDAPS://domain.com etc.)
string path = "LDAP://domain.com:636";
var ldapConnection = new DirectoryEntry(path, "loginName", "password");

ldapConnection.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure; // Works perfectly
ldapConnection.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Encryption; // Doesn't work
ldapConnection.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer; // Doesn't work
```

Both Authentication Types that doesn't work throw the same exception:

> System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException (0x8007052E):
> The username or password is incorrect.

Firstly I saw that I'm missing a Certificate Server on my AD DS and installed it. But after installation I get the same error. I might need to install/configure more things. If so, then please share resources what needs to be done.

**My questions:** Do I need any prerequisites (e.x. on the AD DS) to be able to use `AuthenticationTypes.Encryption` or `AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer`? Or do I need a different user for using this Authentication Types?
Any Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ldapConnection.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure | AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer;
```

`Secure` defines the type of authentication that is used, whereas `SecureSocketsLayer` defines the type of connection. They serve different purposes, so they can be used together.

But really, you don't need to specify anything. The default is `Secure`, and if you specify port 636, it will use SSL since that's the only way the server would accept the connection on that port. That's why it works when you only specify `Secure`.

That's also the reason it fails if you specify `SecureSocketsLayer` by itself. Once you specify anything, the default (`Secure`) is discarded and only what you specify is used. Without `Secure` it will try basic authentication (AKA "simple bind"), which is probably disabled on your domain.

More reading in the documentation for the [AuthenticationTypes Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.authenticationtypes).

Comment: Thank you for that detailed explanation - it makes sense! But can you also explain me how I can test if the connection now uses SSL? Is there any standard software for this purpose? My own research pointed me to the "Event viewer" but I don't understand where I can see that if the connection is now encrypted.

Comment: If you specify port 636 and it works, then you know it's using SSL. The AD server will only accept SSL connections on that port. But if you want to satisfy your curiosity, you can use something like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org) to look at the network traffic. You will see an SSL handshake when the connection is established.